# How can firefox change the wallpaper when the administrator blocks that feature?

Tags: firefox, desktop-customization

Firefox is able to change the desktop background, despite that feature being blocked by my admin. How do they do it?

Comment: The more relevant question is how your admin did it. Just blocking the default UI method obviously is not sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Group Policy setting locks the user interface so you cannot change the wallpaper via the normal route, but does not prevent a registry key modification via other means (such as Firefox or Paint).

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper` is set to `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Desktop Background.bmp` directly by Firefox.

I guess users can be denied write permission to the registry entry, but I wouldn't really recommend it.